# Electron app dock menu right click context menu customization on MacOS

Tags: electron

I am studying handling of multiple browser windows in electron app.

Now I want to customize dock menu right click context menu on MacOS.

[image]

My app has the main browser window which is a big window and right click on dock menu show like above image.

In my app, I also provide to switch to small window mode. Which is another secondary browser window. When this secondary browser window is showed, then main browser is hide. Currently the dock menu is like below.

[image]

Issue: The small secondary window can launch another child window which is frameless, I use it to micmic as dialog. Electron provided dialog box cannot achieve what I want. But new another browser window, when right click, it will show like below:

[image]

But I don't want to know that frameless window in the dock context menu.

I checked the electron dock customization documents, seems not find way to achieve what i want to solve for my issue.

Does anyone handle this kind of behaviors or any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.